# Toggle button is not working, menu does not slide down properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have quiz menu when i click on it ,it slide down showing four divs on a single div.
Here is the fiddle: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zaiby/gqr2j8b5/3/).

Here is the html:

toggle button quizes

```
<ul>
  <li id="togglebtn"class="quizli"><a href="#">Quizes</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div id="quizmenu" class="bubble">

                        <div id="subdiv1" class="subdiv">
                            <h5><img src="image/earth.png" alt="earth">WorldGK</h5>
                                <a>gffdfd</a>
                                <a>gfdddd</a>
                                <a>gfddddd</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="subdiv2"class="subdiv">
                            <h5><img src="image/computer.png" alt="earth">Computer</h5>
                                <a>gfdddddd</a>
                                <a>gfddddddd</a>
                                <a>gfddddddd</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="subdiv3" class="subdiv">
                            <h5><img src="image/dictionary.png" alt="earth">English</h5>
                                <a>gfgdfdfdfd</a>
                                <a>gfdfdfd</a>
                                <a>gfdfdfdfdd</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="subdiv4" class="subdiv">
                            <h5><img src="image/code.png"     alt="earth">Programming</h5>
                                <a>C#</a>
                                <a>gfgfdgfdgfgfd</a>
                                <a>gfdffgfgf</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="subdiv5" class="subdiv">
                            <h5><img src="image/inter2.png" alt="earth">Interview</h5> 
                                <a>ggdfgfdgfd</a>
                                <a>gfgfdgfdgfgfd</a>
                                <a>gfdffgfgf</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

This is the css:

Answer (score 0):

`.scrollup :hover` should be `.scrollup:hover`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the opacity to 1 but the opacity is already 1.

maybe you can set the opacity of 0.5 for the normal state, then at hover 1.

try this:

```
.scrollup {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  right:50px;
  bottom:50px;
  position:fixed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  background: url('http://s29.postimg.org/59qiyrlab/freeiconmaker_1.png?noCache=1447752779');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size:contain
}

.scrollup:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I have added an additional

```
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .4s ease;
 transition: all .4s ease;
```

to smooth things a little.